# DVD similar menu for USB with mp4 movies that work on SmartTV with USB?

Tags: video, mp4, usb

I have converted my old VHS-movies to MP4 and put them on a USB to be able to watch them on my smartTV which works well. However, I want a DVD-simular menu where I can have a description, and maybe a picture of each movie and links to play the movies instead of folders and long lists that the USB memory presents them when I put the flash drive in my TV. Is this possible? I know I can solve this by connecting a computer to my TV or cast to the TV (e.g Chromecast) but it is not a solution I am looking for.

My first solution was to make a simple html page that opens in TV browsers but html is not viewable on a USB in my TV. See the image below which formats it supports.

It supports the file format *.flv and thought I could make a simple page in old adobe flash but *.flv only supports moving images and not integration with buttons/links. I guess I need *.SWF-file to make a menu.

I have tested several programs that can create DVDs and menus of movie files (mp4) because my TV can handle *.vob, the problem is that it also converts my mp4-files to DVD format. I want to keep them in mp4 (they should be untouched as they are already optimized) and only add the DVD menu.

I found this [HowTo create DVD-like Menus in MP4 - MP4Menu](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=410970) which seems to be something for what I want to accomplish but seems very complicated and the thread is 19 years old and thinks it should have gotten a little better since then.

Is it possible to create a menu with a descriptive text for my movies that I have on a USB to my smartTV (not an android TV)?

[image: Compatible Video Formats]

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a really good reason for doing it this way, I would do this in the cloud - ie make a [private playlist on YouTube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3127309?hl=en-GB) or similar service, and use the Smart TV to access YouTube instead of trying to build something the TV might not do very effectively. Plus when you change your TV, it is likely to still work on your next device.